# Как по айди сообщения узнать его содержимое

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Как зная айди сообщения узнать его содержимое, автора, время и т.д.? Пробовал bot.get_message() но такой функции нет

```
@bot.command(name="test")
async def _test(ctx, message):
    msg = bot.get_message(message)
    await ctx.send(msg.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Зато у `discord.TextChannel` есть асинхронный метод `fetch_message`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
@bot.command(name="test")
async def _test(ctx, message_id: int):
    msg = await ctx.fetch_message(message_id)
    await ctx.send(msg.content)
```

Если нужно получить сообщение не из текущего канала, то стоит запросить еще и `id` канала в котором это сообщение находится:

```py
@bot.command(name="test")
async def _test(ctx, channel_id: int, message_id: int):
    msg = await (bot.get_channel(channel_id)).fetch_message(message_id)
    await ctx.send(msg.content)
```